# Mysql return today's result before future date results

Tags: php, mysql, join

```
SELECT `user_appoint`.`ApptDateTime` AS ApptDate,`user_appoint`.`id` AS appt_id,        `user_appoint`.`ref_no` AS ref_no, `user_appoint`.`status_id` AS status_id,  `user_det`.`pass_no`, `user_det`.`f_name` AS fname, `user_appoint`.`date`, `user_det`.`l_name` AS lname, `user_det`.`dob` AS dob, `tbl_pi`.`Pi`, `tbl_vesselmaster`.`id` AS Vid, `user_det`.`id` AS user_id, `user_appoint`.`dr_comments` AS Remarks
FROM (`user_det`)
JOIN `user_appoint` ON `user_appoint`.`u_id` = `user_det`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `tbl_pi` ON `user_appoint`.`id` = `tbl_pi`.`ApptId`
JOIN `tbl_rank` ON `user_appoint`.`rank` = `tbl_rank`.`rank_id`
JOIN `tbl_typeofmedical` ON `tbl_typeofmedical`.`Id`=`user_appoint`.`purpose`
JOIN `tbl_vesselmaster` ON `tbl_vesselmaster`.`id` = `user_appoint`.`vessel`
JOIN `tbl_clinic_list` ON `tbl_clinic_list`.`Id` = `user_appoint`.`ClinicId`
JOIN `pate_status` ON `pate_status`.`id`=`user_appoint`.`status_id`
LEFT JOIN `tbl_doctorlist` ON `tbl_doctorlist`.`id`=`user_appoint`.`DrId`
LEFT JOIN `tbl_fleetvessel` ON `tbl_fleetvessel`.`VesselId` = `user_appoint`.`vessel`
WHERE `user_appoint`.`void` =  0
AND `user_appoint`.`comp_id` =  '123'
AND `user_det`.`3cc_id`  LIKE '%%'
AND `user_appoint`.`ref_no`  LIKE '%%'
AND  `user_appoint`.`DrId`  LIKE '%%'
AND  `tbl_fleetvessel`.`FleetId`  LIKE '%%'
AND  `ApptDateTime`  LIKE '%%'
ORDER BY `user_appoint`.`ApptDateTime` DESC
LIMIT 15
```

This is myquery which return following result

```
ApptDate                      f_name       l_name  
--------------               -------      -------
13-11-2015                    xyz           pqr
06-11-2015                    abc           uio
04-11-2015                    qwe           jkl
```

I want the table to show today's result on top followed by future results and then the rest of results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the order by clause of your query:

```sql
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(`user_appoint`.`ApptDateTime`, '%d-%m-%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d-%m-%Y') DESC, `user_appoint`.`ApptDateTime` > NOW() DESC, `user_appoint`.`ApptDateTime` DESC
```

That way the first result is the one where the date matches today, the next results are those where the date is greater than today (=in the future) and then the rest in descending order.

Comment: What kind of field is `ApptDateTime`? Date or Datetime? The name suggests Datetime, but the output suggests Date

Comment: Its a datetime field. I am using php so i have changed the date format on view side. its stored in  this format '2015-11-11 09:45:00 ' in database

Comment: I've updated my answer to make sure that both the date field and the value for today (`NOW()`) are in the same format when comparing. That should fix it...I hope :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use CASE WHEN with your conditions in your ORDER BY:

```
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN DATE(user_appoint.ApptDateTime) = CURDATE() THEN 1
    WHEN DATE(user_appoint.ApptDateTime) > CURDATE() THEN 2
    ELSE 3
  END
```

Comment: Just to improove myself, wouldnt calling CURDATE on a var, then comparing to that be more effective (faster)?... also, you have a mispelling on the function, it should be `CURDATE() `

Comment: @Bonatti: Thanks, I've corrected the typos. And no, to use a variable for the date would not be faster. CURDATE will only be called once for the query anyhow.